# Display dynamic PDF from network drive in React App with Node server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pdf, blob, fs

I am having trouble to display a pdf file, which is located on a network drive, in my React app.

First, I tried to directly set the source property of the iFrame to the path where the pdf is located. Trying this, I got an error that chrome won't load local resources due to security reasons.

After some research I tried to fetch the file on the node server and sent it to the Client. That's where I'm stuck right now.

Part of my code on server side:

```
function getTestDoc(req, res, next) {

  var file = fs.createReadStream("R:\Test.pdf")
  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.sendFile(file);
}
```

Part of my code on client side:

```
function getTestDoc() {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    responseType: "blob",
    headers: authHeader(),
  };

  return fetch(`${apiUrl}/mo/gettestdoc`, requestOptions)
  .then((response) => {
    const file = new Blob([response.body], {type: "application/pdf"})
    const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file)

    window.open(fileUrl))
}
```

When the new Window opens, there is an error saying "Error while loading the PDF document.".

What am I doing wrong? I am thankfull for any suggestions.

PS: the general connection between server and client is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

Code on server side:

```
filePath = "\\\\servername\\path\\Test.pdf"
var file = fs.createReadStream(filePath)
var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
res.setHeader('Content-Length', stat.size);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'inline; filename=Test.pdf');
file.pipe(res);
```

Code on client side:

```
return fetch(`${apiUrl}/mo/gettestdoc`, requestOptions)
  .then((response) => {
    response.blob()
    .then(blob => {
      const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      window.open(fileUrl);
    })
})
```